# Test for Lookup

Tags: apex, unit-test, lookup

I've got the following APEX:

```
public Contact accountLookup {
  get;
  set;
}
```

And in the constructor:

```
accountLookup = new Contact();
```

With the following on the Visualforce page:

```
<apex:inputField value="{!accountLookup.AccountId}" />
```

This looks at the Account field on the Contact object and generates a Lookup ability to the Account object.

Where this works, I'm struggling to figure out how to write a test for this.

In my test class I'm creating an Account as follows:

```
Account a = new Account(
    Name = 'My Company'
);

INSERT a;
```

And want to put that generated account in the `public Contact accountLookup` variable. The problem is that when I try to do this, I'm getting the error:

> Illegal assignment from Account to Contact

With `controller.accountLookup = a;` and the error:

> Illegal assignment from Id to Contact

with `controller.accountLookup = a.Id;`

I understand I've created a Contact object in order to generate the lookup, but I'm unsure of exactly how to make the Account I've generated work for said Contact object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to this

```
controller.accountLookup.AccountId = a.Id;
```

You need to assign account id and then continue with your flow in the code.

Comment: Perfect! I knew it'd be super simple but just couldn't quite wrap my head around what I was missing. Thank you.

Comment: Absolutely, in precisely 7 minutes! ;)